# ImageBackground not working in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

function Welcome() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/background.png')}
      resizeMode={'cover'}
      style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <Text>Sign up</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Welcome;
```

I am trying to make my image fit the entirety of the screen (just like a background).
And this just simply does not work. There are no errors with my source or anything. As a matter of fact, the image only loads where there are components. So, in this case, the image only loads behind the "sign up" text. Not the entire screen.

It will be awesome if anyone could help me with this problem. (I am new to react-native so I apologize in advance if I am asking some dumb question)

Comment: Is `Welcome`  children of another component? This can happen if Welcome is inside another `View` without style set to `flex: 1`. If that's the case just make sure all parents have style and are `flex:1`. Then, you  shouldn't need `width: '100%', height: '100%'`

Comment: I appreciate the comment! I made some changes after seeing this, now it loads perfectly. (Still have to get rid of the header, don't really know how to do that. Got to do some research) Thank you!